# Laravel Schedule Call Helper Function Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to run a Helper function (App\Helpers) on a scheduled timer using Laravel (for testing purposes I have it running once every minute). I'm using Laravel 5.3.

This is my schedule function in my Kernel.php...

```
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function()
        {
            // Calling this function should write a new file with a random number in it.
            // I know this works perfectly fine outside of the scheduled task because I 
            // call it in other places, and it works)

            FileEdit::UpdateFile();

        })->everyMinute();
    }
```

The issue is that the `FileEdit::UpdateFile()` part is NOT ever being called by the laravel at the designated time intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running a cron job to execute the schedule command every minute?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction

`* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

> This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. When the schedule:run command is executed, Laravel will evaluate your scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

Comment: Huh? No, it's my understanding that scheduling has done away with the need to run a cron job.. I mean it's an option, but it states that a call function like I outlined should work...

Comment: The cron job tells the schedule to run every minute.  Then every minute, Laravel determines what to do according to your `Kernel.php` file.  Something still has to tell Laravel to turn on every minute.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, assuming you have cron configured correctly, this may help you debug your issue https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#task-hooks

Still I would double check if your cron is working, and set according to https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction